# Bootstrap 3 selector for changing from md to sm responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I change (or what to add to the class) the following code so that when the browser changes to small size, the label Name 2 is directly under the label Name 1 and the input txtName2 is directly under the input txtName1?  Here is the code:

```
<form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" runat="server">  
 <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtName" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name 1:</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" style="width:300px" />
        </div>
       <label for="txtName2" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name 2:</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" id="txtName2" name="txtName2" style="width:300px" />
        </div>
   </div>
```

So my Small device "look" should be something like:

Name 1:  txtName1

Name 2:  txtName2

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite any html code and add special class

```
hidden-sm
hidden-md
hidden-lg
```

For example

```
<div class="hidden-sm">this will be hidden only on sm width size, in others will be showen</div>
```

This class can be added what ever you want. Using this class you can totally change layout of you page.

Also remember about basic rules, and it's better to define all types in class for each "lg \ md \ sm \ xs", it's described on official manual by the way.

Comment: I don't understand. I do not want to hide any of the labels or inputs.  I want to rearrange them to be vertically stacked instead of horizontally.  Unless I am missing something in your suggestion.
Thank you

Comment: I think I got it.  You are suggestion to create a different set of label and input for each device (lg, md, sm)?  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: You can do second form with class 'hidden-*'. So you will have two same forms but with different markup\classes. On lg-md (for example) you will see one markup (others will be hidden) on sm-xs another.

Comment: But first of all try @azeós suggest. Maybe it will be your quick solution. Otherwise I think hidden will help you.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  I will have to see if it feasible for me. You see, the example if very simplified. Actually the inputs get populated in the code behind from the database. And I don't know if I can have two inputs with the same ID, while hiding one.  And if I have two different IDs I have the overhead of populating both.  Thank you.

Comment: There can be trouble only on re-bind of jQuery, don't forget that will be posted ONLY form you submitted, others will not. Also if you will do two forms you should add 're-input' in second form, otherwise when you will change width 'new form' will be empty.

Comment: I will play around with these options. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your `col-md-*` with `col-xs-*`. Automatically, when you reach the `xs` size, the input width will be `100%`, you prevent that by specifying a `col-xs-*`. And you should remove your inline width.

**EDIT:**
You have one `form-group` with all your labels and inputs. You should have one for each label-input couple. And you are missing the `.form-control`: [Bootstrap horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Here you have a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/67vuk/1/

**EDIT2:**
I don't know if it is the best way, but you could add a `<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>` before the second label: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4188/

**EDIT3:**
Second approach: http://jsfiddle.net/67vuk/2/

Comment: Azeos.  No, this does not work.  But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Azeos, your fiddle shows the controls in the way I want them to be on the small device. But then I cannot see how to change the positions for the MD device.   Thank you.

Comment: The EDIT2 with clearfix seems to do the job.  I have never used this so I will have to read on what it does.  And test it again.
Thank you very much.